# In memory, should stack bottom and heap bottom have the same address?

Tags: memory, linker, heap-memory, microcontroller, stack-memory

I'm using a tm4c123gh6pm MCU with [this](https://github.com/spirilis/tiva1202/blob/master/TM4C123GH6PM.ld) linker script. Going to the bottom, I see:

```
...
...
.bss (NOLOAD):
{
    _bss = .;
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    _ebss = .;
} > SRAM

_heap_bottom = ALIGN(8);
_heap_top = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM) - _stack_size;
_stack_bottom = ALIGN(8);
_stack_top = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM);
```

It seems that heap and stack bottoms are the same. I have double checked it:

```
> arm-none-eabi-objdump -t mcu.axf | grep -E "(heap|stack)"
20008000 g       .bss   00000000 _stack_top
20007000 g       .bss   00000000 _heap_top
00001000 g       *ABS*  00000000 _stack_size
20000558 g       .bss   00000000 _heap_bottom
20000558 g       .bss   00000000 _stack_bottom
```

**Is this correct?** As far as I can see, the stack could overwrite the heap, is this the case?

If I flash this FW it 'works' (at least for now), but I'm expecting it to fail if the stack gets big enough and I use dynamic memory. I have observed though that no one in my code or the startup script uses the stack and bottom symbols, so maybe even if I use the stack and heap everything keeps working. (Unless the stack and heap are special symbols used by someone I can't see, is this the case?)

I want to change the last part by:

```
_heap_bottom = ALIGN(8);
_heap_top = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM) - _stack_size;
_stack_bottom = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM) - _stack_size + 4; // or _heap_top + 4
_stack_top = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM);
```

**Is the above correct?**

Comment: the heap will grow from 20000488 to 20007000. and stack grows down from 0x20008000 to 0x20007000.  they will collide somewhere between 20000588 and 20008000.  you have not shown all the code though. need to use the right variables in your code, the stack init and the heap init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your own linker script then it is up to you how stack and heap are arranged.

One common approach is to have stack and heap in the same block, with stack growing downwards from the highest address towards the lowest, and heap growing upwards from a lower address towards the highest.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to calculate how much heap or stack you need separately.  As long as the total of stack and heap used at any one instant is less than the total memory available, then everything will be ok.

The disadvantage of this approach is that when you allocate more memory than you have, your stack will overflow into your heap or vice-versa, and your program will fail in a variety of ways which are very difficult to predict or to identify when they happen.

The linker script in your question uses this approach, but appears to have a mistake detailed below.

Note that using the names *top* and *bottom* when talking about stacks on ARM is very unhelpful because when you push something onto the stack the numerical value of the stack pointer decreases.  When the stack is empty the stack pointer has its highest value, and when it is full the stack pointer has its lowest value.  It is ambiguous whether "top" refers to the highest address or the location of the current pointer, and whether bottom refers to the lowest address or the address where the first item is pushed.

In the CMSIS example linker scripts the lower and upper bounds of the heap are called `__heap_base` and `__heap_limit`, and the **lower** and **upper** bounds of the stack are called `__stack_limit` and `__initial_sp` respectively.

In this script the symbols have the following meanings:

`_heap_bottom` is the lowest address of the heap.

`_heap_top` is the upper address that the heap must not grow beyond if you want to leave at least `_stack_size` bytes for the stack.

For `_stack_bottom`, it appears that the script author probably mistakenly thought that `ALIGN(8)` would align the most recently assigned value, and so they wanted `_stack_bottom` to be an aligned version of `_heap_top`, which would make it the value of the stack pointer when `_stack_size` bytes are pushed to it.  In fact `ALIGN(8)` aligns the value of `.`, which still has the same value as `_heap_bottom` as you have observed.

Finally `_stack_top` is the highest address in memory, it is the value the stack pointer will start with when the stack is empty.

Having an incorrect value for the stack limit almost certainly does absolutely nothing at all, because this symbol is probably never used in the code.  On this ARMv7M processor the push and pop instructions and other accesses to the stack by hardware assume that the stack is an infinite resource.  Compilers using all the normal ABIs also generate code which does not check before growing the stack either.  The reason for this is that it is one of the most common operations performed, and so adding extra instructions would cripple performance.  The next generation ARMv8M does have hardware support for a stack limit register, though.

My advice to you is just delete the line.  If anything is using it, then you are basically losing the whole benefit of sharing your stack and heap space.  If you do want to calculate and check for it, then your suggestion is correct except that you don't need to add `+ 4`.  This would create a 4 byte gap which is not usable as either heap or stack.

As an aside, I personally prefer to put the stack at the bottom of memory and the heap at the top, growing way from each other.  That way, if either of them get bigger than they should they go into an unallocated address space which can be configured to cause a bus fault straight away, without any software checking the values all the time.

Comment: Notice that `_stack_bottom` is at the same address than `_heap_bottom`, that is what seems strange to me. When the stack is full, the s.p. should have value 0x20000000 - 0x1000 (4 KB) = 0x1ffff000 (as you explained). That's different from 0x20000558 (_heap_bottom and _stack_bottom). I think the author of the script though that the current linker address would be incremented after declaring `_heap_top`, but that's not the case. It uses `.`, which is at the same address as `_heap_bottom`. Am I wrong?

Comment: My apologies I misread it.  I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: (I mistook which was the problem code and which was your suggested correction)

Comment: >> Having an incorrect value for the stack limit almost certainly does absolutely nothing at all, because this symbol is probably never used in the code. << Then, how does the ARM uP decide what is the initial value of the s. p.? (Having that different MCUs will have different addresses for RAM memory, e.g.: TI is 0x20000000, but STM32 is 0x80000000 as far as I remember)

Comment: The initial value of the stack pointer is the first entry in the vector table.  This obviously has to be correct.  The symbol value for the **limit** of the stack is probably never used.